# Windows line endings of pyc file

Tags: server, python

I have problem to run pyc file on one machine with Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS.

This is my source code of the file:

```
#!/root/PycharmProjects/Project/venv/bin/python3.7
print("Hi")
```

When I compile it in python console with commands:

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile('test2.py')
```

I get test2.cpython-37.pyc file. Then I add execution access by

```
chmod +x test2.cpython-37.pyc
```

If I run

```
./test2.cpython-37.pyc
```

on first machine (Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS) I get simple "Hi".

But if I run similarly compiled file on other machine with the same OS - Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS, I get:

```
./test2.cpython-37.pyc: line 1: $'B\r\r': command not found
./test2.cpython-37.pyc: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./test2.cpython-37.pyc: line 2: `z�p^=�@s
                                          ed�dS)ZHiN)�print�rrtest2.py<module>�'
```

It looks like it is reading Windows line endings. But why? It is created, compiled and run on Ubuntu machine.

How can I solve this issue, and run this pyc file with the right result on second machine?

**EDIT:**
On both machines it is the same result of

```
ls /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc

register  status
```

Comment: I wonder if the hard-wired interpreter in the shebang doesn't exist on the other machine - so it defaults to trying to run the compiled python code in the shell?

Comment: I chcecked it, interpreter exist in that path.

Comment: I changed shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python` and result is the same.

Comment: Hmm... in any case, I don't think it's related to Windows line-endings (at least, not directly) but to the fact the the python3 bytecode's file magic number happens to contain the hex sequence `0d0d`. See for example [How to find out the magic number for the .pyc header in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53833665/4440445)

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `ls /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` from the two machines?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: OK so that's another dead end - my understanding is that direct execution of byte-compiled python required binfmt support, so I was expecting one to have it and the other not. See for example [Shebang for compiled Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21826136). Is the `binfmt-support` package installed on both?